# Error message "Application does not take parameter " in function col

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

**Hello**,

I would like to create a column containing multiple instances of groups where each group contains a label and a groupValue.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

col("groupingCriteria"(0)("label"))
col("groupingCriteria"(0)("groupValue"))
```

Intellij say me under 'label' or 'groupValue' : "Application does not take parameter"

I have not this message when i am using $ of sparkSession.implicits._ but i don't want use this keyword

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

By looking into your requirement, it seems you need a column 'group' which would be of ArrayType. You can create a schema for this first, then apply to your DataFrame.

The following code creates a schema with two parent level columns id, group (where each group contains a label and a groupValue as per your requirment). Then the schema is inferred to an empty DataFrame, in actual case which would be replaced by proper data. It might help you.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType,StringType,StructField,StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

//build a spark session
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("myApp")
  .getOrCreate()

val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext

val myDfSchema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("id", StringType, true),
  StructField("group", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
    StructField("label", StringType, true),
    StructField("groupValue", StringType, true)))), true)))

val myDf = sparkSession.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], myDfSchema)
```

The schema looks like following.

```
scala> myDf.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- group: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- groupValue: string (nullable = true)
```